# Can I use Rundeck from its .jar file without DNS configuration?

Tags: java, linux, web, dns, rundeck

I am trying to use Rundeck from the .jar file.  I use a Java command to start it up on my Linux (CentOS) server.  From a work station, I open a web browser and go to the IP address of the Linux server over port 4440.  After I log into the web UI, the URL changes from an IP address to the host name of the Linux server.  The web browser displays "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED."

My authentication is successful.  But I do not have a record on my DNS server for the host name.  I will not be able to get the systems administrator to update the DNS server either.  I do not have administrator permissions on the workstation with the web browser that I use to connect to the Rundeck server.  I therefore cannot update the local hosts file.

Is it possible to use the .jar file for Rundeck without resolution of the host name of the Linux server from the workstations that try to use the web UI of Rundeck?  If so, how?  I try to re-type in the IP address.  But I am unable to get the web UI to work.  The IP address keeps changing to the hostname.  The hostname never resolves to an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the rundeck-config.properties file:

```
grails.serverURL=http://<ip-address>:4440
```